# jQuery AJAX queue checkbox filters and send request to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

Hi I am creating a site using Laravel, jQuery & AJAX. I have multiple checkbox filters on a page that is sent to the server using AJAX and the results are filtered on the front end of the website. Now the problem I have is that everything a checkbox is changed a request is sent to the server; which I want to amend. I want to instead queue this in an array or something similar so that I can send it to the server every minute or perhaps when the last request has finished. But I'm not entirely sure how I would do this.

This is the code I have so far;

```
$('#filters input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e) {
        console.info('Thank you for selecting "' + $(this).attr('value') + '"');
filters.update('/index/filter',$('#filters :input').serialize(), '&offset=0', true);
    });
```

a typical filter looks as follows;

```
<input type="checkbox" id="tag_982" name="region[]" class="essex checkbox form-filters" value="Essex" data-name="Essex">
```

and the request is sent as follows;

```
var filters = {
    update: function(url, data, offset, reset) {
        var count = '&count=40';
        if (typeof offset === 'undefined') {
            data = data + count;
        } else {
            data = data + count + offset;
        }
        $('.loading-icon').fadeIn();
        $('#adverts').addClass('loading');


        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(json) {
                console.log('Adverts successfully loaded');
                $('.loading-icon').fadeOut();
                $('.append-data').html(json.data.viewData);

                $('#adverts').removeClass('loading');

                $('.info-num').html(json.data.offset + ' of ' + json.data.total + ' adverts');


                if (json.data.offset >= json.data.total) {
                    $('#load-more').children('a').text('All adverts loaded').contents().unwrap();
                } else {
                    $('#load-more').children('a').text('Show more adverts');
                    $('#load-more').children('a').attr('href', json.data.offset);
                }

            } // end success
        }).done(function() {


        }); //end ajax
    }, //end update function
} //end var filters
```

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be achieved? I'm looking for some basic examples.

Comment: Use `setInterval` and create a function which performs `ajax` operation based on the list saved..

Comment: Why do you not want the request to be sent immediately, or why do you want to schedule it every minute? If the user changes the checkbox, then refreshes the page, their request will never get made.

Comment: @BadHorsie, I don't want to overload the API i am sending the requests too